# For loops and removing rownames

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to remove the row names for all of my data using a for loop to make it shorter, but It is creating a new value called "i" rather than removing the rownames

this is the example of my code where U91, etc are my data.

```
for (i in c(U91,P95,P98,E10)) {
  rownames(i) <- NULL
}
```

I have also tried using quotations inside the c() and still an error this instead creates an i value of "E10"

Another Problem I'm having with is trying to loop this function:

```
Caltex <- Main[Fuel=="Caltex", ]
for (i in c("7-Eleven","Caltex","Indie")) {
i <- Main[Brand==i, ]
}
```

Comment: Are `U91` etc. `data.frames`, variables, or what kind of object?

Comment: You probably don't want to combine the data.frames with `c` (check what that creates). But more importantly, `i` contains a copy of these objects. The original objects can't be modified with this approach.

Comment: U91,etc  are data.frames

Comment: @Roland so how would i do it instead?

Comment: You put them all in a list, look at @joel.wilson's answer.

Comment: You provide a minimal reproducible example and you have a high chance of getting help. You don't provide one and you have a low chance of getting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rownames(dataframe)` returns 'string' of  vector. So, if want to remove or to do any operation of 'rownames' try to create a vector of string. 
for example:
`c("U91","P95","P98","E10")` and then 'rownames(i) <- NULL'

to answer your second question: Please remember you are handling `string`. String does not work the same way it works for numbers.
Please explain your second question elaborately about your variables and string input. So, that I could help on this.

Comment: Understood, So the second one It is trying to create a new dataframe from an existing dataframe where under the fuel column where the value is called Caltex. And i'm trying to do this to multiple fuel names.

Comment: First of all if `Fuel` is a column then syntax will be `Caltex <- Main[,which(Main[,"Fuel" ]=="Caltex")]`  gives you all values under that `Fuel` column. Now Caltex is a variable. So you can directly use as it is in a loop. So, create a list of variables and start accessing variable one by one and run the loop. again in the for loop for assign to new dataframe syntax will be `Main[,'Brand'] <- i` where `i` is your variable in the loop. Please let me know if this serve your purpose.